# How to display 24H Volume Coinmarketcap API

Tags: php, api

Hi I am having a problem displaying the 24 H volume name in coinmarketcap api it roduces an error when i call it but other values are working perfectly it may bebecause the 24h volume starts with a number. I want to know how will i get it. Thank you. Here is my current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>


<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Symbol</th>
<th>Rank</th>
</tr>
<?php   
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
// $tick = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/');
$url ='https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start=0&limit=1000';// path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$characters = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

// echo $characters[0]->name;

foreach ($characters as $character) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $character->name . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->symbol . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->rank . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->price_usd . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->price_btc . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->total_24h_volume_usd . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $character->market_cap_usd . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->available_supply . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->total_supply . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->max_supply . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->percent_change_1h . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->percent_change_24h . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->percent_change_7d . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $character->last_updated . '</td>';

echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>sdsdf
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access fields named in that fashoin you need to wrap them with `{''}`. So you need to write `$character->{'24h_volume_usd'}`.